# path not working properly when using capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2, capybara

I'm using rails 3.0.5, rspec2 with latest capybara.

Routes setup like:

```
scope "(:locale)", :locale => /de|fr|it|en/ do
  resources :dossiers
end
```

In application_controller I have this:

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  options[:locale] = "es"
  options
end
```

So in my views I can use

```
link_to 'test', dossier_path(1)
```

without any problems.

But when I do the same in capybara's visit it tries to use the 1 for the locale and not for the id. It only works when I use

```
visit dossier_path(nil, 1)
```

or

```
visit dossier_path(:id => 1)
```

But both are ugly and looks like a dirty hack. So why do I need to use this dirty hack and what do I jave to do, so that I can use the path methods just like in the views (so without the dirty hack of having to add nil or explicitly pass :id => ...)? :)

Comment: The title of your question indicates that this is an answer rather than a question. After reading the content, this impression didn't change much. What are you looking for exactly?

Comment: I'm looking for an answer why I need to use the dirty hack I showed and what I can do, so that I can use method just like in the views (so without the dirty hack of having to add nil or explicitly pass :id => ...).

Comment: Sorry, I just saw the title was wrong. Instead of "now" it should have been "not", I just fixed it ;)

Comment: it seems capybara is not passing through your application controller, that's why it can't go through your paths properly. what you can do is to make a step helper to fix your routes for capybara

Comment: could you please give me an example? it should not only work for dossier_path, but any path method. if you add it as an answer, i can vote for it :)

Answer (score 7):

I ran into a similar issue. You can set the default_url_options in a before block like this in request specs:

```
 before :each do
   app.default_url_options = { :locale => :es }
 end
```

Comment: Just to put a bit more context for this: The code above should be somewhere within the `Rspec.configure do |config|` block.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the route generation happens outside of Application Controller. And Capybara doesn't do any magic to provide default url options from it to route helpers.

But you can specify default locale inside your routes.rb

```
scope "(:locale)", :locale => /de|fr|it|en/, :defaults => { :locale => "es" } do
  resources :dossiers
end
```

And now if you don't pass :locale option to a route helper it will default to `"es"`. Actually, it isn't necessary to keep `def default_url_options` anymore in your controller.

Comment: How about defaults which are dependent on the current_user for example?

Comment: This is bad answer, even I have upvoted it at first. It makes your tests pass, but half of the link in the app itself are being stuck with in default locale.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running rails 3.2.6 and I use a technique that I found here https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/255 under Phoet's comment.  Just put this somewhere in /spec/support and it should cover all your specs

```
class ActionView::TestCase::TestController
  def default_url_options(options={})
    { :locale => I18n.default_locale }
  end
end

class ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet
  def default_url_options(options={})
    { :locale => I18n.default_locale }
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Opposite as shown [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) under **Using Capybara with RSpec** the only way I've been able to get it working is writing

```
visit user_path(:id => myuser.id.to_s)
```

so for you it *should* be

```
visit dossier_path(:id => "1")
```

Does it work?

Comment: Sorry, I dont see how this is related to my question concerning default url options not being used?