# Can't pass :locale to Capybara's method visit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, capybara

my Capybaras test only work for the default locale, not for a specified one.

```
describe "How it works" do
  it "should have the content 'how it works'" do
    visit how_it_works_url(:locale => :en)
    page.should have_content('How it works')      
  end
  it "should have the content 'wie es geht'" do
    visit how_it_works_url(:locale => :de)
    page.should have_content('Wie es geht')      
  end
end
```

If the default_locale is 'en', the first test passes, if it is 'de', the second one passes.

Neither the route is translated (I use the gem 'rails-translate-routes') nor the content.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps:

Path not working properly when using [capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396866/path-not-working-properly-when-using-capybara)

For rspec you can put this snippet in a `spec/support/locale.rb` for example:

```
# workaround, to set default locale for ALL spec
class ActionView::TestCase::TestController
  def default_url_options(options={})
    { :locale => I18n.default_locale }
  end
end

class ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet
  def default_url_options(options={})
    { :locale => I18n.default_locale }
  end
end
```

Look [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/255) for more details.